# Handling 0s in a generalized linear model---climate data

Tags: error, glmm, gamma-distribution, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

[image]

I am using a generalized linear mixed model for analyzing climate data and incidence of a disease variable. The data follows a gamma distribution. But I am getting the following error when I am running glmm with gamma family and log link:

Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) :
non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family

My data has 0s and I can't get rid of them in anyway. I looked up extensively for this error but did not find any satisfactory answers. I did come across glmmTMB package of r which talks about zero inflated and hurdle models, did not get that completely too. Got a sense that it is more suitable for Poisson distribution count data. But mine is not count, it has a lot of decimals but the distribution is non-gaussian.

Any lead on this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have $0$s in your response variable, then your data are not gamma-distributed. Why fit a gamma model?

Comment: Hi Dave, I have added the density plot of the data which is giving me the 0 errors above. So by looking at the density plot what distribution I should fit?

Comment: zero inflated negative binomial

Comment: Thank you. Isn't zero inflated negative binomial model for count data? Mine is not count data, it is continuous data with decimals. Also can you suggest a good source for reading about this?